# In highstock 1.3.0, when zooming in full, the graph draws all messed up

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have tested with various graphs and this seems like a consistent problem.

I have a highstock graph, if you draw a lot of data and zoom out to the full view of the graph by using the sliders or the range selector, the whole graph draws all messes up.

I found an example fiddle that illustrate the issue.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/highcharts/qgprf/show/

I've used Chrome to get the path that highstock generated and then plotted just the path:

http://jsfiddle.net/MsFhh/

It's obvious that highstock is creating some tomfoolery.

For the sake of stackoverflow, here's some code

```
  alert("I R code"); //Copying the huge svg path in here is kinda insane
```

Is there something that I can do to fix this?

PS: if I upgrade to the new highstock version, everything in our graphs breaks so updating is not an option :(

Comment: From your question and the examples, I can't work out what the problem is. I suggest you persist with trying to keep to the latest version of highstock, as you will probably get more help from the developers.

Comment: Also discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1651).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been fixed. The fix for version 1.3.5 can be found here:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651#issuecomment-25226662

Don't use the patch though. It doesn't fully fix the issue. It seems like 1.3.6 fixes everything that were causing the defect.

The patch can be seen here:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/9607afd512473710b6aeb9bfceaf23549d285ff0

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug of Highstock 1.3.0, alread y fixed in 1.3.3+. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651). You can modify sources to fix issue, or upgrade to latest version.

If you have issue with upgrading - let us know what kind, and we will try to fix them. Of course working fiddle with that issues is really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the new version and immediately ran into 3 other defects that were cause by the new version. Currently the 1.3.0 version seems to be the more stable option. However, the corrupt graph is a big problem. I'm kind of stuck because none of the options presented can help me :(

I will supply better examples as soon as I've met my current deadline. I'll also try and illustrate my problems with the new version as soon as I can.

Comment: I have tried the new 1.3.4 version of HighStock. The problem is less severe but still present. In the fiddle, just click the "all" button and observe: The last half of 2012 draws different. This creates very unsightly artefacts in some data sets. jsfiddle.net/ka4sc

Comment: Added comment to [this report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651) - looks like only 1.3.2 works properly for a while and this is regression bug.

Comment: This is still a big issue with hardly any movement on fixing the bug. We are close to launch and our client is getting very uneasy about the possibility of getting this bug resolved :(

Comment: Feel free to add comment, that this is showstopper for you, devs should prioritize this bug.

Comment: A fix is now provided at https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651#issuecomment-25226662

Comment: This issue has not been completely fixed yet:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651#issuecomment-25920538